# Binary Tree Node Insertion

Tags: binary-trees, binary-search-trees

I was trying to implement a Binary Search Tree using this article as a reference: [Binary Search Tree in JavaScript](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-binary-search-tree-javascript/).

I was thinking especially about the node insertion method. Here's my implementation:

```
class BinaryTree {
// ... initialization
add(val) {
    if(this.root === null) {
        this.root = new Node(val);
        return ;
    }
    this.addNode(val, this.root);
}
addNode(val, node) {
    if(!!!this.comparator) throw new Error('this.comparator cannot be undefined.');
    let comp = this.comparator(val, node.val);
    if(comp === -1) {
        if(node.left === null) {
            node.left = new Node(val);
            return ;
        }
        this.addNode(val, node.left);
    }
    else if(comp === 1) {
        if(node.right === null) {
            node.right = new Node(val);
            return ;
        }
        this.addNode(val, node.right);
    }
}
// ... other methods
}
```

where `this.comparator = (v1, v2) => { return (v1 <= v2) ? -1 : 1; };`

My questions are:

- Is there a way to modify this `add` method such that it can balance the tree after every addition?
- If so, by factor would the time complexity of `add` be growing?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree

Answer (score 1):

Search & read on AVL trees that follow the BST rules while keeping a worstcase balance difference of 1 between subtrees.
read  knuth sorting & searching

Comment: I will definitely look into it.

Comment: I may think of mapping a linear insertion algorithm that keeps OATs optimal to the case where all weights r equal, but since u didn't learn about AVL trees yet this may be difficult and probably beyond the scope of the course u r in now

Comment: By linear insertion, do you mean something similar to this:
`const mid = 50;
        tree.add(50); // root
        for(let i=0; i<mid; i++) tree.add(i);
        for(let i=mid+1; i<101; i++) tree.add(i);`?